# A problem on commutator subgroup.

Tags: group-theory

Let $H \leq G$ such that $|G:H|=2. $ Define $[G,G]=  \left \langle {g^{-1}_ig^{-1}_jg_ig_j: g_i,g_j \in G}\right \rangle.$ Prove $[G,G] \subseteq H.$

Could anyone provide some **hints(not solution)** on how to prove this claim?  Thank you.

Comment: Are you familiar with Orbits and what does it mean that $|H:G| = 2$ ?

Comment: This means $H \lhd G ?$

Comment: yes that's correct.

Comment: Thanks, how should I exploit this fact?

Answer (score 1):

Hints(By filling the blanks):

- $[G:H]$ so $H$ is $~\text{_o__al}$ subgroup of $G$.
- $[G:H]=2$ so the qoutient group $G/H$ is $~\text{a_e_ia_}$.
- so for every $xH,~yH\in G/H$ we have $$xHyH=\text{__}~xH\to xyH=yxH\to [\text{_}~,~\text{_}]\in H$$ and so $G'\subseteq H$.

Comment: $|G:H|=2 \implies |G/H|= 2 \implies G/H$ is abelian .

Given any $xH, yH \in G/H, xy=yxh,$ for some $h \in H.$ This means $xyx^{-1}y^{-1} \in H. $

Answer (score 0):

Prove these facts : (Say $aba^{-1}b^{-1}$ one commutator of $G$)

(i) $H\lhd G$ :

> http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Subgroup_of_Index_2_is_Normal

(ii) Conjugate and Inverse of any commutator is also a commutator.

(iii) $[G,G]$ members are exactly finitely many production of commutators.

(iii) If quotient group $G/H$ is abelian, then $[G,G<H]$.

Note that $G/[G,G]$ is, itself, abelian.